# renamed folder becomes a file with an extension

Tags: macos, mac, folders, file-extensions

When I create a folder and name it "test.tmp" the finder asks me if I want to add the file extension ".tmp" to my folder. When accepted, the folder changes to a document with an icon.

I then can no longer open the 'folder' by double clicking on it. There is no default application associated to open the test.tmp file.

If I run ls -l the file is still shown as a directory.

On another Mac I am able to create this same folder name, and the folder remains a folder.

Any idea why on my Mac adding the .tmp changes the folder to a file?

TIA.

Comment: If you remove all the dots in the name it should revert to folder

Answer (score 3):

Folders can have a suffix too. If your OS X System knowns the file extension, it will change the icon (after renaming) and link it to the App that can handle that extension (and is set as default App to open those file types).

The folder then becomes a package or container, where you cannot easily look inside by browsing in finder. But you can right-click on it and choose "Show Package Contents" to see what is inside.

[image: show inside with "Show Package Contents"]

Sometimes the (folder-) file extension is hidden by System Default (as for iPhoto Library containers).

Comment: Since the .tmp file extension does not show a default app, it seems that the OS X System has a use for temporary folders.

Comment: @pknz which OS X System version is affected?

Comment: I am running 10.8.5.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve this issue from information here.

Basically associate the file extension with another app, ie Calculator, then clear the associated by running this command in Terminal:

```
`locate lsregister` -u /System/Applications/Calculator.app
```

followed by:

```
xattr -d com.apple.ResourceFork *file_which_won't_open*
```

This clears the extended attributes on the file.

Full details below:

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57326949-263/how-to-clear-custom-application-associations-in-os-x/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the solution above could not solve the problem, because the macOS would restructure the association soon later(environment is macOS 11.15.7).

So I download an unnecessary app from the AppStore and change this extension file default `open with` it, such as `Xnip.app`. After running command as below delete this app from LaunchPad quickly.

```
`locate lsregister` -u /Applications/Xnip.app
```

If you download this app again, it will associate with it again. This is not perfect solution, but worked for me.

Comment: Please look at the [faq] to understand how the site works, how good answers should be written and how reputation can be gained.